# How do i bind multiple events to several elements using the for loop in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, bind

hai. I have been learning jS lately. How do i bind multiple events to several elements using a loop? Here is an example of what i am trying to do. Lets say i have several divs with the ids $box1, #box2, #box3 ... #box9 etc. why doesnt this work? ( im using jquery ).

```
for (var i; i<8; i++){
    $('#box' + i).click(function(){alert('hai')});
}
```

I know that i can do the same thing instead like this:

```
$('div').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){alert('hai')});
});
```

However i d like to know why the first code snippet wouldnt work as i intended it to.

Comment: As a side note, creating functions within a loop is not a good idea. You should declare the function as a variable before the loop. Better yet, you should define a common class for all the elements that have the same onclick behaviour and use a class selector instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript, simply defining a variable using `var i;` doesn’t make it zero and "loopable".

So you simply need to assign a number to the `i` variable.

```
for (var i = 0;
```

Also note that you can’t know what `i` is inside the callback due to JavaScript closure.